# Join 3 tables using Doctrine_RawSql object

Tags: php, mysql, join, doctrine

Is there any way to make this select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `sf_guard_user` 
JOIN `friendship` 
  ON `friendship`.`user_id` = `sf_guard_user`.`id` 
JOIN `circle` 
  ON `friendship`.`circle_id` = `circle`.`id` 
WHERE `circle`.`id` = 1 
ORDER BY `circle`.`id`
```

with a Doctrine_RawSql object without using foreign keys?

Comment: What do you mean when said "without using foreign keys"?
By the way, why would you like to use RawSql instead of DQL?

Comment: I meant without relations between tables.I use MyISAM as my storage engine, so I cannot create foreign keys and, implicitly, cannot use relations between those tables(those that are created in schema.yml).Anyway, I managed to create the query using Doctrine_Manager object:                                                                                                                        Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM sf_guard_user u JOIN friendship f ON u.id = f.user_id JOIN circle c ON f.circle_id = c.id WHERE c,id = 1 ORDER BY c.id ASC")

Answer (score 1):

Why did you decide to use Doctrine_RawSql?

In this example, I'm using `inner join`:

```
SELECT sf.* FROM `sf_guard_user` sf
INNER JOIN `friendship` f on  f.`user_id` = sf.`id` 
INNER JOIN `circle` c on f.`circle_id` = c.`id` 
WHERE c.`id` = 1 
ORDER BY c.`id`
```